# Executing PDO statement with more parameters than defined

Tags: php, pdo

I have an array that contains more variables than necessary. Is there any way to avoid the error: Invalid parameter number

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password');

$user = [
  "firstname" => "John",
  "lastname" => "Doe",
  "street" => "abcdestreet 123"
];

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = :firstname AND lastname= :lastname");
$statement->execute($user);   
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
   echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."<br />";
   echo "Email: ".$row['email']."<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: `$user [` ? missing the `=`?

Comment: Yes, leave out the 'street', your query only used 'firstname' and 'lastname'.

Comment: Yes, i forgott the = but that should just show an example :)

Comment: The whole thing is in one method, and user array can have multiple values that are not used for database query and I cannot edit or delete something from database

Comment: What's the problem to take only parameters from this array used for the database query?

Comment: This is one possibility. I already tried to use a second array with the only needed values of $user. But in reality, instead of 2, a whole 20 values are needed. there it gets a bit confusing. So I am looking for some ideas to make it easier

Comment: Well keep looking because what you are asking is impossible

Comment: You're going to need to build an array which contains only the variables necessary for the query. It's not very clear, but if you're varying the query so it can dynamically contain a different number of parameters at execution  time, then you'll need to vary the parameter array at the same time

Comment: Create an array of acceptable values. If the query is static, then you know exactly what fields you're looking for. If the query can change, then you'll need a broader list of what's allowed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could try is to filter the input array to only include keys that match parameter names in the prepared statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = :firstname AND lastname= :lastname";

$values = array_filter($user, fn($k) => preg_match("/:$k\b/", $sql), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($values);
```

This will work for your example, and I think should work in general for what you're trying to do. The regex should be adjusted to not match things in quotes that look like parameters, which I don't know how to do off the top of my head, but I'm sure there are some examples of things like that around here. The odds of accidentally having something like that that happens to match one of your keys don't seem too high, though. If there are some other instances of things it shouldn't match that I haven't thought of, I think the worst thing that could happen is that you'll get the same error you're already getting.